# Android listview item.setSelected() cannot keep it highlighted when showing contextual action mode

Tags: android, listview, contextmenu, selection, highlight

I am studying how to use the contextual action mode according to the official document at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#CAB

However, everything works fine except for that the selected item cannot keep highlighted as expected(am I supposed to?) when I show the contextual action mode.

I tried to set the list selector with selective drawables, set the item view background with selective drawables but all ended in vain.

Could anybody help me out?

My code is listed below:

```
import com.robin.huangwei.omnigif.content.GifStore;

import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks;
import android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader;
import android.support.v4.content.Loader;
import android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.view.ActionMode;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>, OnItemLongClickListener{

    private static final int LOADER_ID_GIFIMAGES = 0;
    private SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter;
    private ListView mListView;

    private ActionMode mActionMode;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(LOADER_ID_GIFIMAGES, null, this);

        String[] from = new String[] {GifStore.GifImages.Media._ID, GifStore.GifImages.Media.DISPLAY_NAME};
        int[] to = new int[] {R.id.item_icon, R.id.item_name};
        mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.icon_text_item, null, from, to, 0);

        mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        mListView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
        mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        mListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Media._ID, MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME};
        CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(this, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null, null);
        return cursorLoader;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor c) {
        mAdapter.swapCursor(c);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
        mAdapter.swapCursor(null);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        if (mActionMode != null) {
            return false;
        }

        mActionMode = startSupportActionMode(mActionModeCallback);
        view.setSelected(true);
        mListView.setDrawSelectorOnTop(true);
        return true;
    }

    private ActionMode.Callback mActionModeCallback = new ActionMode.Callback() {

     /**
      *  Called each time the action mode is shown. Always called after
      *  onCreateActionMode, but may be called multiple times if the mode is invalidated.
      */
        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode arg0, Menu arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }

        /*
         * // Called when the user exits the action mode
         */
        @Override
        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode arg0) {
            mActionMode = null;
        }

        /*
         * Called when the action mode is created; startActionMode() was called
         */
        @Override
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            MenuInflater inflater = mode.getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_list_item_context, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.menu_list_item_context_edit:

                break;
            case R.id.menu_list_item_context_star_unstar:

                break;
            case R.id.menu_list_item_context_delete:

                break;

            default:
                return false;
            }
            mode.finish();
            return true;
        }
    };

}
```

Comment: you mean when you long press on an item in the list?

Comment: Yes I do exactly as the tutorial told me to do. I call view.setSelected(true); in the long click call back.

Comment: show how you setup your listview. did you set your choice mode to `MODAL`?

Comment: you also might have to use `setDrawSelectorOnTop(true)`

Comment: I did not use MODAL since I want my application to support old devices. And I even tried to use CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODEL but still no help. I have posted my code.

Comment: instead of using `setSelected` try using `setItemChecked`

Comment: I understand that to use setItemChecked I have to make a checkable view and set the background myself. I am just wondering if the framework could provide a more convenient way of doning this. So, it is my fault that to expect the item to be kept highlighted after setSelected?

Comment: you said you already made a selector so all you have to do is add the state `activated` to it

Comment: I just used state selected and pressed, and just tried activated ended in vain. I think the state of the view is reset after onLongClick is called. If there is no convenient way of doing this, I will fall back to use checkable view items.

Comment: @Robin : Even I am facing the same issue...did u find any solution for this?

Comment: @Abhinav : No, I haven't got a way to make it work on old Android. So I fallback to use if(SDK > 10) { use MODAL } else { use simple context menu }